# Find limits of series: $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+x)(1+x^2)\cdots(1+x^{2n})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, infinite-product

Find $$\ \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+x)(1+x^2)...(1+x^{2n}), \ |x| <1$$ 
What i have done is  $$\ \lim_{n \to \infty}(1+x)(1+x^2)...(1+x^{2n})\ =\ \lim_{n \to \infty}\ (1+x)\ \ \ \lim_{n \to \infty}\ (1+x^2)...\ \lim_{n \to \infty}(1+x^{2n})\ \ $$

Is this correct?

Comment: @graydad yeah.my apologies

Comment: Life would be easier if we were looking at $(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)\cdots (1+x^{2^n})$. Could that be the intended product?

Comment: That is not enough. You want to say something about a quantity like $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^{2n}a_k$$ and not just $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$$

Comment: The question as it stands does not belong to elementary calculus. Rather it belongs to the theory of theta functions. Like @AndréNicolas said, it would be much simpler if $2n$ is replaced by $2^{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean $|x|<1$, and that the product you are trying to evaluate is given by
$$
a_n=(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)\cdots (1+x^{2^n}).
$$
Then consider $(1-x)a_n$:
$$
\begin{align*}
(1-x)a_n&=(1-x^2)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)\cdots(1+x^{2^n})\\
& = (1-x^4)(1+x^4)\cdots(1+x^{2^n})\\
&=\cdots =1-x^{2^{n+1}},
\end{align*}
$$
so therefore
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1-x}.
$$